# Porque al ingresar un elemento a un arreglo dinámico en java los elementos anteriores son remplazados por este, quedando todos iguales

Tags: java

Al igual que a David Calderon en junio del 2016, me ocurre que en Netbeans, cuando ejecuto el procedimiento de guardar un elemento en el arreglo dinámico;

```
@SuppressWarnings("SillyAssignment")
private void guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    empleado obrero = new empleado(valnombre,valcedula,valbasico,valdias,valprestamo,valventa);
    if ("A".equals(opera)) {
        personal.add(obrero);
    }else{
        personal.set(reg, obrero);
        opera = "A";
    }
    mostrar();
    limpia();       
}
```

si con anterioridad ya se ha agregado el primer elemento, entonces al agregar el segundo, el primero toma los valores del segundo, y quedan dos elementos exactamente iguales. y si se hace por tercera vez el ingreso de un nuevo elemento, automáticamente los dos elementos anteriores toman los valores del tercer elemento grabado, esto ya me había ocurrido antes, con arreglos estáticos de objetos, y después de hacer muchos cambios el solo se arreglaba, pero tambien despues de un tiempo volvia a ejecutar los programas y volvían a fallar por lo mismo, quiero saber si les ha ocurrido y si existe alguna manera de evitarlo, aclaro que las 2 respuestas que se le dieron a david Calderon no solucionan este problema, parece que es un problema del netbeans, o de la maquina, o del sistema operativo windows 10. 
de antemano gracias por la atención que puedan prestarme,
atentamente,

JAIME DIEGO

Comment: Revisa que los campos en tu clase `empleado` (que debería llamarse `Empleado`) no sean `static`.

Comment: Gracias Luiggi lo voy ha hacer

Comment: Es totalmente correcta la soluccion de Luiggi, gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola, porque no añades el código problemático a la pregunta, así @LuiggiMendoza podría escribir el comentario como respuesta y generemos potencial de aprendizaje para los demás? Saludos